# Handler_read_key description

Tags: mysql

As per MySql documentation link:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Handler_read_key

> Handler_read_key - The number of requests to read a row based on a key. If this value is high, it is a good indication that your tables are properly indexed for your queries.

Can someone please explain / simplify / elaborate this definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A value of thousands per second is pretty normal.  (Manually compute Handler_read_key / Uptime.)

Do the following to get a better feel for what it, and its siblings, are about:

```
FLUSH STATUS;  -- resets the Handler counters (and a few other things)
SELECT ...
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler_%';
```

You will see `read_key` for "point queries" and for "range queries", possibly one each.  You will also see a larger value for a "range query" in `read_next`.

`Handler_write%` values indicate that a temp table needed to be built and reread -- such as for `GROUP BY` and/or `ORDER BY`.

I find the `Handler` values to be handy in comparing two queries -- bigger numbers is a good indication of a less-well optimized query.

If you like, present us with a small number of `SELECTs`, together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT` and the `Handler%` values.  We can go into more details 'by example'.

**Handler_read_key**

I *think* `read_key` is bumped by one in these cases:

- Reaching into a table, either for a specific row, or to start a range scan.
- At least once per table in a query with multiple tables due to `JOIN` or subqueries.
- Once per row in a "nested loop join".  This is the *usual* case for a simple `JOIN` two tables.  It scans the first table (one `Handler_read_key`, many `Handler_read_next`) and reaches into the next table repeatedly (many `Handler_read_key`)

Think of it this way:  Most reads from a table work in 1 or 2 steps:

- Use a "key" to find *the* row (or the *first* row of a range) --> `Handler_read_key` bumped by 1.
- If multiple rows needed, then get the "next" row --> `Handler_read_next` bumped by 1 *per extra row*.  If using something like `ORDER BY .. DESC`, then bump `Handler_next_prev`.

Comment: Can we say, whenever there is increase in handler_read_next value, there would be increase in handler_read_key?
Under which condition, increase in handler_read_key would be more than 1 for a single query?

google doc for sample queries: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1W0bz2Qc1JZUhpTexxoo-ENCyr3_60jJBZ3hp95rp1Gs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @vaibhavgupta - see if what I added clarifies it.